# What is the priority about gravity and layout_gravity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gravity

I am testing `LinearLayout` and create a `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextView`s.
the `LinearLayout` has the attribute `gravity="center_vertical"`, and the first `TextView` within the `LinearLayout` has attribute `layout_gravity="top"`.

`gravity="center_vertical"` of `LinearLayout` puts its content in center vertically.

`layout_gravity="top"` of `TextView` tells its container to put me on the top.

So what happened if they are together?

In my experiment, the 'layout_gravity="top"' does not work.

following is my code and result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="textview 1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="textview 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: My result]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the parent element's gravity is the first to be executed. You can't see the effect of layout_gravity top because it follows the gravity set to its parent element. You should not set gravity center_vertical to linearlayout if you don't want the first textview to appear at the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What Jay Bryant Casilang is somewhat correct. It is because of parent's gravity. But there is more. It is also because it is a `LinearLayout`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

A `LinearLayout` designed for views to be "next" to each other, either vertically or horizontally. Because you are setting `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_gravity="top"` on the first `TextView`, what you are hoping to see is this:

[image]

However, this would mean that there would be spacing between the two layouts. Spacing that is "unaccounted" for (no margins, no padding, etc.).

And THAT is NOT allowed in `LinearLayout`.

all children of `LinearLayout` has to be next to one another in some way (in a linear way, get it?)

Btw, I achieved the top like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="textview 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="textview 2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this was clear.